# Optimizing with Absolute Value Objective Function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

max : $w = |q^T y|$
subject to
$A y \leq b$
$y \geq 0$

Please describe how one could solve the non-linear programming prob. above by using linear programming methods.

I tried changing $y$ to $y' - y''$ in the constraints and $y' + y''$ for the objective function. However, my Excel solver says that "the cells do not converge". How should I solve this?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: the maximum value of $w$ may be infinite. do you have any information about $A,b,q$?

Comment: no, but there's a hint saying: "Try breaking it into 2 linear programming problems. Then, could you think of combining them into just 1 problem?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow the advise given to you, consider two problems:
$$
\begin{cases}
w^+ &= q^Ty^+\to\max,
\\
Qy^+&\leq0,
\\
Ay^+&\leq b,
\\
y^+&\geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
and

$$
\begin{cases}
w^- &= q^Ty^-\to\max,
\\
Qy^-&\geq0,
\\
Ay^-&\leq b,
\\
y^-&\geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $w = \max\{w^+,w^-\}$. Here matrix $Q = (q\quad0\quad\dots\quad0)^T$. 
With such decomposition you just consider two possible cases for the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, is there any way to solve this using just 1 linear programming problem?

Comment: @John: I'm afraid, I don't know such a way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $y = y_1 + y_2$ where $q^Ty_1 \le 0$ and $q^Ty_2 \ge 0$.